# change the name of custom column in oracle contain case

Tags: sql, oracle

I am not able to change the name of the custom column in oracle.

```
SELECT case when sysdate between START_DATE and END_DATE then 'Y' else 'N' end case  as Flag
FROM  EXP_ECO_RATES;
```

It gives me error

> **ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected**.

`START_DATE` and `END_DATE` are the column with Date Data Type.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `case` keyword at `end case`. Oracle expects `FROM` after the `end`, because that's the correct syntax of `CASE`expression, but it finds the `case` keyword hence you got the error-`ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected.`

Change it to:

```
SELECT case when sysdate between START_DATE and END_DATE then 'Y' else 'N' end  as Flag FROM EXP_ECO_RATES;
```

Comment: Thanks For The Quick Response. It's Working Completely Fine now

Comment: According to ANSI SQL the `AS`keyword is optional.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, the problem is the extra `case` keyword.

I want to point out that using `between` with date/time values is dangerous.  In particular, `sysdate` has a time component.

It is safer to use explicit comparisons.  Often in this situation, you intend:

```
select (case when sysdate >= START_DATE and 
                  sysdate < END_DATE + 1
             then 'Y' else 'N'
        end) as Flag
from EXP_ECO_RATES;
```

Comment: Over here if i am using these operators then i guess it should use "<=" instead of "<"

Comment: @RahulGulwani . . . This is adding one day to `END_DATE` and the strict inequality is intentional.

Comment: I want to go in detail. So can you please tell me what is better option. Using addition("+ 1") with query or using operators "<=". In both the case i will get the results. But i wanted to know which one is faster way to get the results.

Comment: @RahulGulwani . . . Because of the misunderstanding between dates with and without time components, I think adding 1 is better.

Comment: Yes. You are right. Thanks for all your support and knowledge.